# Static css files in go/golang server

Tags: html, css, go

How do I serve static css files in go (go version go1.9.1 linux/amd64)?

My present code doesn't work (it does show website but it does not see css). Here is my attempt to use standard file serving using go handler. When I go into page source and click link to css/styles.css it appears it is visible and redirects correctly (is under correct url). I presume I lack knowledge about some step of parsing.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    PORT = ":3000"
    HOST = "localhost"
)

func handleBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("books.html"))
    tmpl.Execute(w)
}

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", fs))

    http.HandleFunc("/books", handleBooks)
    fmt.Println("Listening on " + HOST + PORT)
    http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)
}
```

style.css

```
.body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

books.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Books</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    books
        <li>book1</li>
        <li>book2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My directory tree:

> - src:
>
>   - books.html
>   - main.go
>   - css
>
>     - style.css

Comment: Change href to start with / (e.g. `href="/css/style.css"`)

Comment: still same thing :/

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Take a look at the browser console, specifically the network tab, and see where the browser is looking for the css file and what is the response it's getting.

Comment: that's another weird thing, there is no error at all

Comment: Your css says `.body`, do you have a `body` *class* in your html? `.body` and `body` are not the same.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear the standard ServeMux does not support "relative" path resolution, you need to have a leading slash or it assumes you provided a host, which is not the case here. This `http.Handle("css/", ...` is wrong.

Comment: Ah right, I had the `FileServer` dir confused with the `Handle` dir... My bad

Comment: tried adding <div class="body"> and removing/adding slash from/to css path, still problem persists

Comment: @asdfgh make sure to add something that you can actually see to your css, try `body { background-color: green; }` ( no dot in front of body )

Comment: already tried it, the css file is just not visible from the level of html :/

Comment: Open the browser's network tab, refresh the page, can you see the browser making  a request for the css file? What's the response? Can you see something like this https://imgur.com/a/v1kkki2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with this part:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", fs))
```

After I cleared cache it turned out that the slash in the first argument of http.Handle is necessary. Big thanks to mkopriva, without you I wouldn't have checked it.